# Remove post class twice

Tags: php, wordpress

For my wordpress child theme I'm using a function to remove the post class `has-post-thumbnail`.
This class appears twice so I have to remove it twice with the function below:

```
// Remove specific post_class() from Mytemplate
add_filter('post_class', 'remove_has_post_thumbnail_class', 20);

function remove_has_post_thumbnail_class($classes) {
    if(is_page_template('mytemplate.php') && ($key = array_search('has-post-thumbnail', $classes)) !== false )
    unset($classes[$key]);

    if(is_page_template('mytemplate.php') && ($key = array_search('has-post-thumbnail', $classes)) !== false )
    unset($classes[$key]);
  return $classes;
}
```

It works fine but I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way to do it, hopefully without repeating the `if()` statement twice.

Comment: Since your issue is very specific to Wordpress, your question would fit better to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple foreach loop:

```
function remove_has_post_thumbnail_class($classes) {
    if(is_page_template('mytemplate.php'){
        foreach($classes as $key => $value){
           if($value=='has-post-thumbnail'){
               unset($classes[$key]);
           }
        }
    } 
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you missed a parenthesis... anyway this works like a charm, thank you thank you thank you.